# ES6 closure can be called only after I assign it to a variable

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, closures

Can anyone explain to me why is the first code below not working but the second one does work?

NOT WORKING ↓↓↓ :

```
let call = () => {
    let secret = "HELLO NOOBS";
    let reveal = () =>  {
        console.log(secret);
    }
    return reveal;
}

call();
```

IS WORKING ↓↓↓:

```
let call = () => {
    let secret = "HELLO NOOBS";
    let reveal = () =>  {
        console.log(secret);
    }
    return reveal;
}

let unveil = call();
unveil();
```

Comment: That's because your function returns a function... If you designed it that way, why did you expect it to run the inner function when calling the outer?

Comment: What an idiot I am

Comment: @PennyDreadful: We've all done things like that, don't beat yourself up too much. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`call` returns a function. In your first example, you just call `call`, you don't ever call the function it returns. In your second example, you're calling the returned function, so naturally that's a big difference.

You can also call the returned function directly without using a variable:

```
call()();
```

The first `()` call `call`; the second `()` call the function `call()` returns.

Live Example:

```js
let call = () => {
    let secret = "HELLO NOOBS";
    let reveal = () =>  {
        console.log(secret);
    }
    return reveal;
};

call()();
```

Answer (score 0):

You just returned the function with `call()` to also execute it you should use `call()()`. Like this:

```js
let call = () => {
    let secret = "HELLO NOOBS";
    let reveal = () =>  {
        console.log(secret);
    }
    return reveal;
}

call()();
```

Note that when you use => functions without parentheses they implicitly return whatever value is given.